# Exercise 5.9. of the book A Basic Course in Partial Differential Equations, by Qing Han, about application of strong maximum principle

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

I have a question about exercise 5.9. of the book A Basic Course in Partial Differential Equations, by Qing Han.

Let assume $‎‎\Omega ‎\subset ‎‎\mathbb{R}^n‎$ is a bounded domain and $f$ and $u_0$ are continuous in $\overline{\Omega}$ and $\phi$ continuous in $\Omega \times [0,T]$. Suppose ‎‎$‎u \in C^{2,1} ( ‎\Omega ‎\times (0,T]) ‎\cap ‎C(‎\overline{‎\Omega‎} ‎\times ‎[0,T])‎$‎‎ solves the following equation.

‎\begin{equation*}‎
‎\begin{cases}‎
‎u_t-‎‎\Delta‎‏ ‎u‎=‎ ‎e^{-u} -‎ ‎f(x)‎ & \quad (x,t) ‎\in ‎‎\Omega ‎\times (0,T]‎ \\‎
‎u(x,0)=u_0 & \quad  x ‎\in ‎‎\Omega‎‎ \\‎
‎u(x,t)= \phi & \quad (x,t) ‎\in ‎\partial ‎‎\Omega ‎\times (0,T]‎ 
‎\end{cases}‎
‎\end{equation*}‎

Prove that 
$$ -M < u <T e^{M} +M, \qquad \qquad \Omega ‎\times (0,T]‎‎ $$
where
$$ ‎M=T ‎\sup_{‎\Omega‎} ‎|f| +‎ ‎\max ‎\Big\{ ‎\sup_{‎\Omega‎} ‎|u_0|, ‎\sup_{‎\partial ‎‎\Omega ‎\times ‎(0,T)} ‎|\phi| ‎‎\Big\}. $$

I know that I must apply the strong maximum principle for some candidate $v$ which is defined by $u$. But I do not know how to handle it.

Comment: It is much simpler than that: construct a suitable constant-in space subsolution $\underline u(t,x)=\underline u(t)$ by solving the (trivial) ODE $\frac{d}{dt}\underline u=-\|f\|_\infty$ starting from $\underline u(0):=-\max\{\|u_0\|_\infty,\|\phi\|_\infty\}$, which can be explicited as $\underline u(t)=-T \|f\|-\max\{\|u_0\|_\infty,\|\phi\|_\infty\}$ The maximum principle then gives $u(t,x)\geq \underline u(t)$ in the whole domain (the parabolic boundary conditions are automatically ordered).

Comment: I'll leave you figure out the construction of the supersolution $\overline u(t)$ by solving some other ODE, which is going to be slightly more involved due to the $e^{-u}$ to be taken into account (this nonnegative term was simply discarded in the construction of the subsolution).